Should OSB roof decking be replaced if it was wet?
I recently had our roof replaced after a small roof leak. The roofers replaced one sheet of OSB in the damaged area with new plywood.
Afterwards we tore out the damaged drywall and insulation and ran a dehumidifier/fan for a week in that room. A different sheet of OSB next to the one they replaced is still setting off my moisture meter (maxes at 50%). Not in the whole sheet but in certain areas.
It hasn't seemed to have gotten worse with recent rain but hasn't gotten better. I am wondering if I need to have that sheet of OSB replaced or if it can dry out eventually.
There are a couple of box vents nearby. It’s a vaulted ceiling with about 9” of insulation between the drywall and the decking. The insulation did take up the full space.

Type of roof ventilation?  As long as just wet and does not damage/rot/start coming apart, good ventilation should dry it out.  Replacing it now will require at least a partial roof replacement, and the roofers will probably fight about paying for it, but let them know in writing.

Thanks, there are a couple of box vents nearby, it’s a vaulted ceiling with about 9” of insulation between the drywall and the decking. The insulation did take up the full space, not sure if that’s normal ventilation wise

Should have at least an inch between the insulation and deck for air to move from bottom to top.

You only need to replace it if one or more of these apply:

It's swollen to the point that it causes appearance problems.

It's been wet so many times that it's delaminating (flaking apart).

It's been wet long enough that it's decaying.


Otherwise it'll dry out and be fine, though your "hot roof" situation means that'll take longer than it would with a conventional attic. OSB is constructed with exterior grade adhesive and won't disintegrate from a short-term moisture event.
